# iOS attributed strings -- smallest example

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I recently decided the best solution to a problem I was having was to use NSAttributedString instances.  The documentation seems lacking, at least to a newcomer.  The answers on stackoverflow primarily were of two types:

1. Read the documentation
2. Use AliSoftware's most excellent [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) class.

I really like the second answer.  But I wanted to understand NSAttributedString better, so I'm providing here the smallest (?) example of assembling and displaying an attributed string in case it helps others.

I created a new single-window project in Xcode (4.5.2) for the iPad using Storyboards and ARC.

There are no changes to the AppDelegate.

I created a new class based upon UIView, calling it AttributedStringView.  For this simple example it's easiest to put the attributed string onscreen using the drawAtPoint: method, which requires a valid graphics context, and that is most easily available within the drawRect: method of a UIView subclass.

Here is the ViewController.m in its entirety (no changes were made to the header file):

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AttributedStringView.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) AttributedStringView *asView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:self.asView];
}

- (AttributedStringView *)asView
{
    if ( ! _asView ) {
        _asView = [[AttributedStringView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 748, 500)];
        [_asView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]]; // for visual assistance
    }
    return _asView;
}

@end
```

And here is the AttributedStringView.m in its entirety (no changes were made to the header file):

```
#import "AttributedStringView.h"

@interface AttributedStringView ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableAttributedString *as;

@end
@implementation AttributedStringView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    NSString *text = @"A game of Pinochle is about to start.";
    //                 0123456789012345678901234567890123456
    //                 0         1         2         3
    _as = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
        [self.as addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:36] range:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
        [self.as addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:36] range:NSMakeRange(10, 8)];
        [self.as addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:36] range:NSMakeRange(18, 19)];

        if ([self.as size].width > frame.size.width) {
            NSLog(@"Your rectangle isn't big enough.");
            // You might want to reduce the font size, or wrap the text or increase the frame or.....
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self.as drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 100)];
}

@end
```

Comment: Why the custom view? Just add a `UILabel` and assign the `attributedText` property. That would make an even simpler example.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?  That you want to know more about NSAttributedString? If this is not a question but "example" code for others it doesn't belong as a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: maddy, you are right, of course, that UILabel has an attributedText property.  My reason for posting this (Robotic Cat) was to get a discussion started around this.  If you search for questions relating to NSAttributedString you don't find any help here that really shows how to create attributes.  The documentation is really thin, like saying a dictionary of attributes, but there's no indication of how to get a range in there.

Comment: Rather than using `[self.as drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 100)]`, try using the full `[self.as drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 100) withAttributes:drawAttr]` where drawAttr is an NSDictionary of key/value pairs: `NSDictionary *drawAttr = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"boldSystemFontOfSize", @"36", @"italicSystemFontOfSize", @"36", nil];`. You might try putting in "range" as a Key and `NSMakeRange(0, 10)` as a Value.